# Resending SMTP mail

Tags: windows, email, smtp, iis-6

I'm trying to resend mail that went into the badmail. I've put it in the Pickup folder, but when I turn the SMTP back on it moves to Drop.

[image: Folder Structure]

Does anyone know why this is happening, and how I could easily resend these mails?

Thanks in advance!